# Model and ViewModel Consept MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to read some data from database and do some process on them and then view them in the view.
I read a lot about MVVM and now I am confused.
Imaging I read a person entity from database with Name attribute.

please make a small code and show me how should I make my model and ViewModel.
I guess it we will be something like this :

```
    public class PersonModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private string Name;
        public string name
        {
            get
            {
                return Name;
            }
            set
            {
                Name = value;
                onpropertychanged("name");
            }


        }
        public PersonModel( string s)
        {
            name = s;
        }

        public void onpropertychanged(string PName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged !=null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PName));
            }
        }
    }

public  class PersonViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection <PersonModel> list { get; set; }

        public PersonViewModel()
        {
            list = new ObservableCollection<model>();
            list.Add(new model("abc"));
            list.Add(new model("def"));
       }

       public void change()
        {
            list[1].name = "changed";
        }

    }


public  class ViewModelBase
    {
        public PersonViewModel vperson { get; set; }
        public ViewModelBase()
        {
            vperson = new PersonViewModel();
            vperson.change();
        }
    }
```

**Edite : Where should database connections be?**

**Edite :**

```
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding vperson.list[1].name}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Instead of providing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in a model, you can implement it in a ViewModel (Because this interface is used for communication between View and ViewModel) and you store data inside Model. You then retrieve data from database in a service layer and map it to your Models.

Comment: @FCin You mean make and exact same class in ViewModel and set the properties equal to model class ? (as I see in MVVM examples) but why should I do it?

Comment: Note however that there is nothing wrong with implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in a model class.

Comment: @Clemens You know I agree with we have not to use INotifyProPertyChanged in model because I think every single relationship between view and model must be throgh viewmode but this code the only way I found for this propuse.

Comment: The problem with implementing INPC in models is that if you do that then you'll generally want to put collection change notification there as well. And unlike INPC, ORMs will not create an ObservableCollection (say) for you unless you override their entity mappings. Simply replacing lists with ObservableCollections after DB retrieval doesn't work because the ORM will think the lists themselves have changed and save them all out again once you're done, bringing your app to a crawl. Like INPC it can be done, I've done it in both EF and NHibernate, but it's a bit more complex than it first seems.

Comment: @MarkFeldman I am new to wpf and C# , can you explain it more clearly ? What is ORM? and can you show me your solution for this problem with a piece of code please?

Comment: I would add a class that directly handles getting data from the database and then instantiate that class in your viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your classes and is working

```
public class PersonModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            if (_name == value) return;

            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public PersonModel(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class PersonViewModel
{
   public ObservableCollection<PersonModel> Items { get; set; }

   public PersonViewModel()
   {
       Items = new ObservableCollection<PersonModel> { new PersonModel("abc"), new PersonModel("def") };
   }

   public void Change()
   {
       Items[1].Name = "changed";
   }
}

public class ViewModelBase
{
    public PersonViewModel PersonViewModel { get; set; }

    public ViewModelBase()
    {
        PersonViewModel = new PersonViewModel();
        PersonViewModel.Change();
    }
}

//Use the dataContext in this way, will help you with the strong type
xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.ViewModels"

<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:ViewModelBase />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonViewModel.Items[1].Name}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I need ViewModelBase because I will hame many other ViewModel classes and then I will use all of them together in ViewModelBase. Now I can bind everything I want to PersonViewModel too, because I have an instance of it in my ViewModelBase class like this : {Binding viem.list[1].name}

Comment: You can add your view.xaml?

Comment: You need connect the Window.DataContext to you viewmodel

Comment: `xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3.ViewModels"`.             <Window.DataContext><vm:ViewModelBase /></Window.DataContext>

Comment: I did it in codebehind :  this.DataContext = new ViewModelBase();

Comment: Thank you for your effort but I did not mentioned my code does not work , It is ok and worked from the begining , I want to know the right desing of MVVM for this problem.